# thread doesnot update referenced variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<thread>
#include<array>
#include<iterator>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<numeric>//accumulate

int sum_of_digits(int num, int sum = 0) {
    //calculate sum of digits recursively till the sum is single digit
    if (num == 0) {
        if (sum / 10 == 0)
            return sum;
        return sum_of_digits(sum);
    }
    return sum_of_digits(num / 10, sum + num % 10);
}

template<typename T, typename Iterator>
int sum_of_digits(Iterator begin, Iterator end) {
    //not for array temp workout
    T copy(std::distance(begin,end));
    std::copy(begin, end, copy.begin());
    std::for_each(copy.begin(), copy.end(), [](int& i) {i = sum_of_digits(i); });
    return  sum_of_digits(std::accumulate(begin, end, 0));
}


template<typename T, typename Iterator>
void sum_of_digits(Iterator begin, Iterator end, int& sum) {
    sum = sum_of_digits<T, Iterator>(begin, end);
}

template<typename T>
int series_computation(const T& container) {
    return sum_of_digits<T, typename T::const_iterator>(container.begin(), container.end());
}

#define MIN_THREAD 4
#define DEBUGG 
template<typename T>
int parallel_computation(const T& container, const int min_el) {

    if (container.size() < min_el) {
#ifdef DEBUGG
        std::cout << "no multithreading" << std::endl;
#endif
        return series_computation<T>(container);
    }

    const unsigned int total_el = container.size();
    const unsigned int assumed_thread = total_el / min_el;
    const unsigned hardwarethread = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    const unsigned int thread_count = std::min<unsigned int>(hardwarethread == 0 ? MIN_THREAD : hardwarethread, assumed_thread) - 1;//one thread is main thread
    const unsigned int el_per_thread = total_el / thread_count;

#ifdef DEBUGG
    std::cout << "thread count: " << thread_count << "  element per thread: " << el_per_thread << std::endl;
#endif

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    threads.reserve(thread_count);
    using result_type = std::vector<int>;
    result_type results(thread_count);
    results.reserve(thread_count);
    auto it_start = container.begin();

    for (int i = 0; i < thread_count; i++) {
        auto it_end = it_start;
        std::advance(it_end, el_per_thread);
        threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() {sum_of_digits<T, typename T::const_iterator>(it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i])); }));
        //threads.push_back( std::thread{ sum_of_digits<T,typename T::const_iterator>, it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i]) });
        it_start = it_end;
        std::cout << "iterator " << i << std::endl;
    }

    results[thread_count - 1] = sum_of_digits<T, typename T::const_iterator>(it_start, container.end());
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    return series_computation<T>(results);

}


#define SIZE 1000
int main() {
    std::vector<int> array(SIZE);
    for (auto& curr : array) {
        curr = std::rand();
    }
    for (auto& curr : array) {
        //std::cout <<curr<< std::endl;
    }

    int series_val = series_computation<std::vector<int>>(array);
    std::cout << "series val: " << series_val << std::endl;

    int parallel_val = parallel_computation<std::vector<int>>(array, 25);
    std::cout << "parallel val: " << parallel_val << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to calculate the sum of digits(recursive) of a randomly generated vector using `std::thread` but in the `results` vector only the result of the last element(i.e main thread) is stored and the child thread doesnot update the referenced `results[i]`.
What is causing this behaviour?

Also, inside the for loop of `parallel_combination`, this code works

```
threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() {sum_of_digits<T, typename T::const_iterator>(it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i])); }));
```

but this doesnot and the error is:  `Error: '<function-style-cast>': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::thread'`.
What's wrong with the below one?

```
threads.push_back( std::thread{ sum_of_digits<T,typename T::const_iterator>, it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i]) });
```

Comment: Are you aware that you usually don't need to specify template arguments in function calls? For example `series_computation<std::vector<int>>(array)` should just be `series_computation(array)`. The template argument can be deduced from the function argument. With the explicit arguments I find my myself needing to check that the types are given correctly all the time when reading your code.

Comment: On an unrelated note, when you create the vector `results` you set the size of the vector. Then you `reserve` the same size which makes no sense.

Comment: @user17732522
in the second case, by saying `it works` i mean the code runs but doesnot update results while in the second code of second case, it just doesnot compile.Sorry for confusion.
Yeah, you are correct about the second problem. I changed the func name and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a data race here:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread([&]() {sum_of_digits<T, typename T::const_iterator>(it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i])); }));
it_start = it_end;
```

The lambda uses `it_start` and then without any synchronization you immediately modify it in the main thread. Capture `it_start` and `it_end` by-copy. Also `std::ref` is pointless there. You are not passing a reference to the `std::thread` constructor, but just to a normal direct function call. Also, as I mentioned in the comments, template arguments in a function call can be deduced:

```
threads.push_back(std::thread([it_start,it_end,&results](){
    sum_of_digits(it_start, it_end, results[i]); }));
it_start = it_end;
```

---

```
threads.push_back( std::thread{ sum_of_digits<T,typename T::const_iterator>, it_start, it_end, std::ref(results[i]) });
```

fails, because there are two function templates of which `sum_of_digits<T,typename T::const_iterator>` could be a specialization. It is impossible to pass overload sets to functions and since there is no way to deduce which one you mean, it will fail.

---

There are some smaller issues in the code, e.g. pointless `reserve` after resizing/construction of vectors or

```
std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));
```

which is not guaranteed to work, because taking the address of a member function of a standard library function has unspecified behavior. Instead just use a loop:

```
for(auto& t : threads) {
    t.join();
}
```

and possibly some others.